Why does alpha-beta pruning behave like this when applied to tic-tac-toe?
The question in my textbook is as follows:

Circle the nodes at depth 2 that would not be evaluated if alpha-beta pruning were applied, assuming the nodes are generated in the optimal order for alpha-beta pruning.

My answer to the problem was very similar to the following image, instead of circling the nodes they have bold outlines:

My answer differed only in circling (making outline bold) of the square with value 2 (bottom row, second column). Surely if the nodes are generated in optimal order for alpha-beta pruning we would not need to consider the "2" state as it does not affect the minimum.
What is the logic here? or is it just an error in the book?
